# Updating .ear file on websphere (6.1) still runs old code

Tags: java, websphere, ear, websphere-6.1

I have a question regarding updating a application on websphere application server.  The application is already up and running and I just want to update the code which is packaged in a .ear file.  Here is what I thought I should do:

1. stop the application server.
2. go to my enterprise application, select the one I am updating, and click update.
3. point to my .ear file in replace the entire application radio button option.
4. restart my application server.

After doing this and trying out my application, it is still running the old code, which makes me really confused.  The only way I managed to get it to work is to use WinSCP, manually go to the cell directly/installedapps and replace the whole .ear folder.  I dont think this a viable solution moving forward.

Comment: So doing 1) stop server 2) update code 3) rebuild your ear via ant 4) start server
isn't something you want to use? Hot code updates aren't something you want to be doing much of.

Comment: it is what I want to do.  i'm just confused why it would still be running the old code and was wondering how other people deploy their updates.

Comment: those 4 steps are what I follow. What dev/ide tools do you use?

Comment: We actually don't even have to stop and start the servers. We deploy it while the servers still are running, so we are happy with steps 2 and 3. No issues for us.

Comment: You did the correct steps (although you don't need to stop the server). Did you "Save Changes" at the end of the process? Is this a standalone app server, or a Network Deployment version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update existing enterprise application we do not have to stop the application since WAS stops the application before updating the code .

Based on the update you gave i am assuming this is a network deployment manager setup , so possibly problem is with sync is not taking place after updating the app and save .

Are you explicitly invoking sync operation after application update ? If not , i would recommend that.

Still problem persists then most likely for what ever reason nodeagent process is not invoking app expansion into installedApps folder but you can take a quick look at nodeagent systemout.log file or ffdc files to see if there is any clue about expansion process.

As a work-around you can also use EARExapnder.sh/bat tool available /profile_home/bin directory to expand the application into installedApps when the app is really updated in config/cells/cell_name/applications but not under installedApps folder.

I hope this helps. 
Thanks
VT
These opinions are my own.

Comment: interesting option - How does the EARExpander.sh work?  do I just point it to my .ear file and it will expand it into a ear directory and I can paste it into the installedApps folder?

Answer (score 3):

I solved it.  After some intense digging it seems the binary files were expanded into dmgr profile but not my correct node.  After finishing the update instead of clicking save I click review and there is a checkbox to synchronize the nodes, which then did the trick.

Comment: FINALLY SOMEONE WHO DOESN'T JUST SAY "LOL SOLVED". Thanks for posting the solution, helped me a ton.

Comment: @carusocomputing glad I helped!  this question brings back memories of my old totally dysfunction workplace

Comment: How did you solve the shitty workplace problem? I'm still struggling with that.

Comment: I just self taught myself everything through stackoverflow lol.  good luck!

Comment: ;). Kindred spirits my friend, best of luck to you as well.