# Websphere runs old code after deploying new ear file

Tags: maven, websphere, ear

Ear file is not getting updated after deploying on websphere 7.0. It is still running the old code.

I am not getting this issue with every project. But for the specific project it is not getting updated. I tried to clear the target. I checked the timestamp for generated classes. All showing the timestamp of when I did maven install.

I got the below post with same issue:

[Duplicate Post with same issue for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22408032/updating-ear-file-on-websphere-6-1-still-runs-old-code)

`In this, user has commented, "After finishing the update instead of clicking save I click review and there is a checkbox to synchronize the nodes, which then did the trick"`

But I could not see any checkbox in WAS 7.0. Please suggest how could I make that work.

Comment: The linked question refers to WAS-ND, which would have several servers running the applications (as clusters). You may be having a standalone server, where there is only node. There's nothing to synchronize here, as there is only one configuration repository.

Comment: Did you try to restart the server and see if you observe same behavior?

Comment: yes I tries restarting the server. didnt work. I created a branch through GIT. I didnt found out the issue but I created another branch and its working fine now :)